# C++ trouble deleting nodes with only one child in BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm having difficulty deleting a node in my binary search tree. The delete function is part of my Node class, and my findMin function is as well. Below is my delete function...

```
/**********************************************
* Delete
**********************************************/
node* node::Delete(node *root, string stuff)
{
//node *temp;

if (root == NULL) // Searches for value in tree
    return NULL;
if (stuff < root->val) // String is in left subtree
    root->left = Delete(root->left, stuff);
else if (stuff > root->val) // String is in right subtree
    root->right = Delete(root->right, stuff);

else
{   // No children
    if ((root->left == NULL) && (root->right == NULL))
    {
        delete(root);
        root = NULL;
    }
    else if ((root->right == NULL) && (root->left != NULL)) // One left child node
    {
        node *temp = root;
        root = root->left;
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    else if ((root->left == NULL) && (root->right!= NULL)) // One right child node
    {
        node *temp = root;
        root = root->right;
        delete temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    else    // Two children
    {
        node *temp = findMin(root->right); // Finds smallest value in right subtree
        root->val = temp->val;
        root->right = Delete(root->right, temp->val);
    }
}

return root;
}
```

Below is my Destructor, which is giving me a SIGABRT (I'm using Xcode)

```
/**********************************************
* Destructor
**********************************************/
node::~node()
{
    if (left != NULL) delete left;
    if (right != NULL) delete right;
}
```

What my code is actually doing is not only deleting the node I intend to delete, but its child node. What could I be doing wrong? Is it an error with memory allocation? Is it an error with how I set the value to the child node?

Comment: Your debugger is probably the best way to answer this. Use your debugger to place breakpoints in places you suspect problems, reason about what should happen, and then see what actually happens as you step through your code.

Comment: Related, destructors of nodes self-deleting their entirety of subtrees is generally a bad idea, particularly in situations where you want surgical removal of a *single* node.The hoops you have to run through to arrange things *not* to destroy data you intend on keeping isn't worth the price. Better to write a routine to wipe out an entire subtree on-demand. There are other target-based algorithms that will employ this same concept later in your studies, balancing algorithms in particular.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Answer (score 0):

You need to null your pointers to left and right before deleting a node.
You call:

```
node *temp = root;
root = root->left; 
delete temp;
temp = NULL;
```

When you "delete temp" you are deleting a node which still points to root->left and root->right and your destructor insures they are also removed. You should instead do something like this:

```
node *temp = root;
root = root->left;
temp->left = NULL;
temp->right = NULL;
delete temp;
temp = NULL;
```

Also in your destructor you don't need to check if they are equal to null since delete already preforms this check.